# Want to Fetch Shopify Product on Shopify Custom App

Tags: shopify-app

Recently I developed Shopify App on **ASP.NET MVC** now I wanted to display all the products on my Shopify app I read Articles and Documentation but I cant understand that how to fetch all the products on my app need help

Comment: They have forums - https://ecommerce.shopify.com/forums ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you already know App development. 
Now to retrieve all products you can simply make call to JSON api from shopify. One of the way to do that is using cURL.

```
GET /admin/products.json
```

Ref. https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/products/product#index

Shopiy JSON call

[image]